# threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jboss

I am working on GWT-Hibernate application, my application works perfectly on integrated GWT environment and even on external server tomcat. I need to deploy my application on JBoss V 6.0. I am able to successfully deploy my application on JBoss and able to run until on point of execution. At particular button click application threw an unexpected exception: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Normally "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" occurs when java compiler finds 2 different classes with same name in 2 different packages. when you are importing both classes at a time and when you are trying to create object of that class it throws "`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`" exception.

Now I am not able to figure out where compiler is finds my two different class! Is there any method available so that I can know the exact location (i.e Physical path) where it finds the two different path, So that I can remove the bad one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanking You,

Regards,

EDIT :

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/myProj]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public com.proj.client.beans.domain.common.transaction.Document com.proj.server.actions.configuration.DocumentAction.saveDocument(com.proj.client.beans.domain.common.transaction.Document,java.lang.Long)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:361) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:329) [:]
    at com.googlcode.strut2gwtplugin.interceptor.GWTServlet.processCall(GWTServlet.java:138) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.googlcode.strut2gwtplugin.interceptor.GWTInterceptor.intercept(GWTInterceptor.java:49) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221) [:]
    at com.proj.server.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:37) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) [:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221) [:]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50) [:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504) [:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_23]
    at com.googlcode.strut2gwtplugin.interceptor.GWTServlet.processCall(GWTServlet.java:127) [:]
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.proj.server.actions.configuration.DocumentAction.saveDocument(DocumentAction.java:161) [:]
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Can u provide full stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is a generic exception, which can have many causes. Please post a full stack trace, without it it's unlikely we'll be able to help.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? There is usually a root cause in the trace.

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is thrown whenever a method or constructor invoked via reflection throws an exception. You need to get the cause of the `InvocationTargetException` to see why your call failed.

Comment: I have include stacktrace. Please help,

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in `DocumentAction.saveDocument()` at line 161. Something on that line de-references a `null` reference. Fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deploy the code on `jboss-5.0.0.GA`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

[`InvocationTargetException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) doesn't in any way automatically imply two different classes with the same name in two different packages (in fact, I've got a hard time imagining how that situation could lead to that exception).

An `InvocationTargetException` is simply the result when a method invoked through reflection throws an exception on its own.

Do you have access to the stack trace? It should print both the location of the reflection call (near the top) and the actual exception thrown by the invoked code (near the bottom).

Comment: I have include stacktrace. Please help,

Answer (score 0):

The last bit of the stack trace looks relevant here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.proj.server.actions.configuration.DocumentAction.saveDocument(DocumentAction.java:161)
```

The exception that you're describing usually manifests as an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` or even more strangely as `Foo.class != Foo.class`when multiple ClassLoaders are involved.

Comment: I agree !... my code DocumentAction.saveDocument(DocumentAction.java:161) is referring ActivitySchedule class which was having a boolean column activity_schedule_status and we have renamed it to activityScheduleStatus but it still refering to old one and giving me the error Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'activity_schedule_status' which is not available now.

Comment: Sounds like build-environment sickness.  Does a fully clean checkout and build demonstrate the same problem?  You can register a [Instrumentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) implementation that injects a no-op [ClassFileTransformer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) which casts the ClassLoader being used to a URLClassLoader to examine its getURLs() method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim's answer says, `InvocationTargetException` is thrown when a method that is called using `Method.invoke(...)` throws a checked exception.  The actual exception is wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException` which is then thrown.

In this particular case, the stacktrace tells us that original exception was a `NullPointerException` thrown at "DocumentAction.java:161".  Track down and fix the cause of that exception.

---

I don't see any evidence that this has anything to do with different versions of some class.  I'd treat it as a normal NPE to start with, and try to figure where the `null` is coming from.

Comment: surprisingly this code is working fine in GWT Development mode and even in Tomcat !... I have deployed this application on JBoss and there I am facing this problem....

Answer (score 0):

I removed Bundle-Activator from plug-in, and it solved the problem.

```
Bundle-Activator: exploitation.presentation.ExploitationEditorPlugin$Implementation
```